# Deserialize JSON dictionary-like to object with properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm stuck with an awful API which returns the following JSON:

```
{
   "root":[
      {
         "row":[
            {
               "name":"Foo",
               "value":"Some value"
            },
            {
               "name":"Bar",
               "value":"Some other value"
            }, (...)
         ]
      },
      {
         "row":[
            {
               "name":"Foo",
               "value":"Lorem"
            },
            {
               "name":"Bar",
               "value":"Ipsum"
            }, (...)
         ]
      }, (...)
   ]
}
```

I'd like to use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize it as a List of C# objects, so that name will match object property and value will be property value. The class would look like this:

```
class Row
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    (...)
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could deserialize it to a dictionary first, then parse that.

Comment: as a quick fix you could deserialise to `dynamic`, then write some code to process that, find each instance of `row`, get each array item from within that, copy the data into an instance your Row class and add that to your final list. I don't see really how you could get directly to a `List<Row>` just in a single deserialising operation - deserialisation is the process of mapping the data into a directly matching object structure. So if the structure isn't what you want, then you'll always have to write some code to transform the deserialised data into the structure you actually want.

Comment: Use a custom `JsonConverter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom JsonConverter to handle this. Below a simple example that requires some null checks etc, but this gets the idea:

```
    public class RowConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType == typeof(Row[]);
        }

        public override bool CanWrite => false;

        public override bool CanRead => true;

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
            {
                return serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
            }
            else
            {
                JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
                var root = obj["root"];
                if (root != null)
                {
                    var rows = new List<Row>();
                    foreach (var item in root)
                    {
                        var row = item["row"];
                        var newRow = new Row();
                        foreach(var field in row)
                        {
                            // better use reflection here to convert name-value to property setter
                            if (field.Value<string>("name") == "Foo")
                            {
                                newRow.Foo = field["value"].Value<string>();
                            }

                            if (field.Value<string>("name") == "Bar")
                            {
                                newRow.Bar = field["value"].Value<string>();
                            }
                        }

                        rows.Add(newRow);
                    }

                    return rows.ToArray();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Then on your Row class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(RowConverter))]
public class Row
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

If you need to include it in your MVC, in Startup.cs (asp.net core):

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => { options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new RowConverter()); });
```

Comment: Works great apart from the fact that line JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader); returned n-element of root, not the whole collection, so i had to get rid of one foreach. Thank you very much for great answer!

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can convert it to dictionary for your single "row" property:

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

And after create dynamic object:

```
private static dynamic DictionaryToObject(IDictionary<String, Object> dictionary)  
{  
    var expandoObj = new ExpandoObject();  
    var expandoObjCollection = (ICollection<KeyValuePair<String, Object>>)expandoObj;  

    foreach (var keyValuePair in dictionary)  
    {  
        expandoObjCollection.Add(keyValuePair);  
    }  
    dynamic eoDynamic = expandoObj;  
    return eoDynamic;  
}  

private static T DictionaryToObject<T>(IDictionary<String, Object> dictionary) where T : class  
{  
    return DictionaryToObject(dictionary) as T;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make classes like below then use newtosnsoft

```
public class root
{
    public List<row> row {get;set;}

}

public class row
{
   public string name {get;set;}
   public string value {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: That's precisely what I want to avoid. I'd like the name from json become an object property, and json value become a value of this property.